# CSS help for popup text over image

Tags: java, css, image, popup

all

I have tried to find this online but don't know where to start, any advises would be great, I am trying to build an interactive page "how to use" for our website, basically this page will be just an image of the home page, so when hovering over certain section of this image a popup text will display explaining what this is?

I have found ways to popup text for hovering over image but it's the whole image not certain section within, any ideas or this is not possible?

Cheers

Comment: java or javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mouse hover message display over certain parts of image jquery/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445591/mouse-hover-message-display-over-certain-parts-of-image-jquery-js)

Comment: Are you building this in java? Javascript is more suitable for this kind of job. You can use HTML and Jquery(Javascript library). Some [tutorials].(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687566/learning-javascript-in-one-weekend)  specifically [map tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) for your purpose.

Comment: This is called an [image map](https://codepen.io/ksenia/pen/BFDtA)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***SVG Imagemap***. Just a example. This site should help too. [Online Image Map](https://www.image-map.net/)

```css
body {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#lynskey circle,
#lynskey polygon {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#lynskey text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#lynskey polygon:hover,
#lynskey circle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#lynskey polygon:hover+text,
#lynskey circle:hover+text,
#lynskey circle:focus+text,
#lynskey polygon:focus+text {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  #lynskey text {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}

#lynskey {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

#lynskey svg {
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/lynskey-med.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

@media all and (min-width: 750px) {
  #lynskey svg {
    background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/lynskey-large.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="lynskey">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 586">
    <title>Lynskey 2015 Backroad Bike Technical Details</title>
    <circle cx="770" cy="401" r="172" />
    <text x="320" y="570">DTSwiss TK540/X.9 wheelset</text>
    <polygon points="256,29 443,29 443,60 357,101 266,65" />
    <text x="0" y="120">Selle Italia X1 Flow Saddle</text>
    <polygon points="646,133 367,159 245,350 283,409 390,434 413,379 456,370 500,400 677,207 684,229 697,217 669,133" />
    <text x="415" y="250">Titanium frame</text>
    <circle cx="225" cy="401" r="51" />
    <text x="320" y="570">SRAM Apex rear dérailleur</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```